# How to automatically repair the grub on debian 9 in each boot

Tags: debian, grub

As the title says, I need an automatic way to repair the grub in case it breaks.
I have a pc with local servers (Nginx, PostgreSQL, etc.) in a store, in this city the power cuts are very common and when that happens, the grub breaks.
When the power failure occurs, the following boot shows a grub rescue with error: unknown filesystem

On one occasion he tried to force an fsck but he did not do the trick.
The only way so far is to physically go to the place with a flash drive with a live ubuntu, install the boot-repair and fix it.
I can not be available at all times when a power outage occurs, I would need a solution that in each boot makes a repair even if it is not needed, but I don't know how to adapt what I do with the boot-repair (graphically) to this situation.

Thank you very much in advance.
If something was not understood, sorry for the English

**Version: Debian 9.7.0 64-bits**

Comment: perhaps grub needs to be installed on a small read-only SSD

Comment: Your problem is not GRUB, and even not OS-related for that matter. The only reasonable solution is to use a UPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power cuts are not GRUB-seeking missiles. The fact that a GRUB rescue mode starts indicates that the core image of GRUB is in fact OK; it is just failing to read its configuration from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

The `unknown filesystem` error makes me think that there is some sort of filesystem issue, and `boot-repair` might be fixing it as a side effect, perhaps by doing a filesystem check.

Modern filesystems are fairly robust against filesystem corruption caused by sudden loss of power, but the robustness usually only covers the integrity of filesystem structure itself: if the data your application needs was not written to the disk before the power was lost, no amount of filesystem checking is going to reconstruct it.

If the system is important for the running of a business, that means its failure could cause clear, quantifiable monetary losses. Is losing even a single day of business cheaper than the price of a small [Uninterruptible Power Supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply)? No? Then my first recommendation would be: **stop trying to apply one-time quick-fixes and get an UPS to eliminate the problem altogether.**

How is your partitioning? If your `/boot` directory is part of the root filesystem, and the filesystem type is XFS, and the fact that the filesystem has not been cleanly mounted might be causing problems for GRUB's read-only XFS driver. In that case, a better fix might be to split off `/boot` as a separate filesystem with a simpler filesystem type, perhaps `ext3`. You could even keep the separate `/boot` filesystem mounted read-only, or even completely unmounted most of the time: it only really needs to be accessible from inside the OS when installing kernel updates or updating your initramfs file.

Is the system using UEFI firmware or a legacy BIOS? This will affect the types of alternative bootloaders available.

You could even grab the system's kernel (`/boot/vmlinuz-*`) and initramfs (`/boot/initrd.img-*`) files, and the kernel boot options from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, and prepare an USB stick that boots the same kernel & initramfs combination with the exact same options. Once the kernel gets started and has its initramfs content and boot options fed to it, it matters little *how* the system got to that point. A boot from such a USB media would be almost indistinguishable from a regular boot from a system disk.

(If legacy BIOS is used, the kernel won't necessarily even have any way to know from which media it was booted from; with UEFI, the `BootCurrent` boot variable will offer a clue, but it is not usually used for anything by the OS.)

That would get the system up to initramfs at the very least: from there, you could get better diagnostics to understand what kind of failure is actually happening, and would in fact have a good chance of having the problem fixed automatically by default, whether by the automatic journal recovery executed by the kernel's full-featured filesystem driver, or by an automatic filesystem check whenever filesystem errors are detected.